# How to execute a function that runs after all the DOM is loaded in nuxtjs?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I created a function that adjusts the size of columns in a table.

When I navigate between pages, it doesn't launch.

If I refresh the page, thanks to SSR, they execute correctly (because the dom is entirely constructed before the javascript is executed).

This is not the case for navigation between pages.

```
<script setup>
// Function to adjust column widths
const adjustTableColumnWidths = () => {
    const tables = document.querySelectorAll('.prose table');

    tables.forEach((table) => {
        const totalWidth = table.offsetWidth;
        const firstColWidth = totalWidth / 3; // Largeur de la première colonne
        const otherColWidth = (totalWidth - firstColWidth) / (table.rows[0].cells.length - 1); // Width of other columns

        // Go through all table rows to fit columns
        Array.from(table.rows).forEach(row => {
            // Ajuster la première colonne
            const firstCell = row.cells[0];
            if (firstCell) {
                firstCell.style.width = `${firstColWidth}px`;
            }

            // Adjust the other columns
            for (let i = 1; i < row.cells.length; i++) {
                const cell = row.cells[i];
                cell.style.width = `${otherColWidth}px`;
            }
        });
    });
};

// Call the function after the content is loaded and rendered
onMounted(async () => {
    await nextTick(); // Wait for the next 'tick' for the DOM rendering to complete
    adjustTableColumnWidths();
    // Add an event handler for window resizing
    window.addEventListener('resize', adjustTableColumnWidths);
});

// Clean event listener when unmounting component
onUnmounted(() => {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', adjustTableColumnWidths);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [Lifecycle Hooks](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/hooks)

```
const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp();

// Called on Suspense resolved event.
nuxtApp.hook('page:finish', adjustTableColumnWidths);

// After page transition onAfterLeave event.
nuxtApp.hook('page:transition:finish', adjustTableColumnWidths);
```

see all the available hooks [here](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/advanced/hooks#app-hooks-runtime).

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't know about it and ChatGPT never offered it to me. You are better than him… haha!